# Install MS Access 2013 alongside Office Home and Business 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access

I currently have Office Home and Business 2010 (64 bit) installed on my computer (running Win7), and the trial period of Access has just ended. I don't want to purchase a whole new office suite if it's not necessary. Can I install Access 2013 as a stand alone program alongside Office 2010? I've looked everywhere for a copy of Access 2010 for purchase, but it seems that MS has done a bang-up job of pushing the newest version. If this is a repost, I apologize.

Comment: What makes you think you can't? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2):

I have Office 2010 and Office 2013 both installed.  Of course programs that provide additional features that intergrate into say Outlook ( i.e. iCloud ) indicate their add-on won't work given this unsupported configuration.

In other words it will work but its unsupported.  One should point out that the file formats for Office 2010 and Office 2013 are slightly different.  You can continue to use the legacy format but the newer format isn't compatible between 2010 and 2013 and there to date is not a compatiblity pack for Office 2010.

[Access 2010 - Physical](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0039L2XD4)

[Access 2010 - Download](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005O24FG4)